# Laravel Eloquent - Trait vs Observer

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Lets say I have some models with the field "slug". On model saving, I want to set the slug automatically.

My first guess to do this, was to create an observer and reacting on the "creating" event. But after a short google search, I found https://github.com/spatie/laravel-sluggable

Why do they prefer Traits over Observers? When to use Traits , when should I use Observers?

Answer (score 1):

[Observers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#observers) are nothing new but classes in Laravel Framework

> You may use observers to group all of your listeners into a single class. Observers classes have method names which reflect the Eloquent events you wish to listen for

But [Trais](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php) are for reusing codes

> Traits is a mechanism for code reuse in single inheritance languages such as PHP. A Trait is intended to reduce some limitations of single inheritance by enabling a developer to reuse sets of methods freely in several independent classes living in different class hierarchies.

You use the package's trait in model and it does all the slugging-mechanism

Comment: Yes, I know the difference between them, but I don't understand, why spatie prefered traits over observers in this case. You want to fill up the slug field based on the name field when the saving event is triggered. Sounds like a job for observer for me?

Answer (score 0):

The package of `Spatie` you linked uses traits to implement the code to your `model`, they listen to the `events` [[here]](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-sluggable/blob/master/src/HasSlug.php#L23) just like you would do in an `observer`.

So they do it to make it easy to implement these features, via the `trait`.